# Laravel Multi Tenancy Return Ambigous Key

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

In my laravel Project i am Using multi tenancy and when I make a join between my tables using Elequent it returns Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous
this is my Tenancy Code :

```html
<?php
namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

trait MultiTenintable
{
    public static function bootMultiTenintable()
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            static::creating(function ($model) {
                $model->user_id=auth()->id();
            });

            static::addGlobalScope('user_id', function (Builder $builder) {
                
                return $builder->where('user_id', auth()->id());
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every query you will make will have a `where user_id = ?` so you have to enforce the table name :

```
 public static function bootMultiTenintable()
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            static::creating(function ($model) {
                $model->user_id=auth()->id();
            });

            static::addGlobalScope('user_id', function (Builder $builder) {
                
                return $builder->where((new self())->getTable() . '.user_id', auth()->id());
            });
        }
    }
```